# SpriteKit Clicker Game Select Spawn Area for Clickable things?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm New to SpriteKit and build a simple CLickerGame in SpriteKit. Now i have the game finish but the thing which should spawn to click on it, spawns from time to time outside the screen. Where can i select the arc4random area where the thing should spawn?

```
@implementation MyScene

-(void)CreateTestObject 
{
    SKSpriteNode *TestObject = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"TestObject"];

    int maxX = CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame);
    float ranX = (arc4random()%maxX) + 1;

    int maxY = CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame);
    float ranY = (arc4random()%maxY) + 1;

    TestObject.position = CGPointMake(ranX, ranY);
    TestObject = CGSizeMake(75, 75);
    TestObject = @"Object";

    [self addChild:TestObject];
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size 
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size])
    {
        bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bg.png"];
        bg.position = CGPointMake(160, 284);
        bg.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
        [self addChild:bg];

        [self CreateTestObject];
    }
return self;
}

-(void)selectNodeForTouch:(CGPoint)touchLocation
{
SKSpriteNode *touchedNode = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:touchLocation];

    if([[touchedNode name] isEqualToString:@"TestObject"])
    {
        SKSpriteNode *TestObject = (SKSpriteNode *)[self childNodeWithName:@"TestObject"];
        TestObject.name = @"DisabledTestObject";

        SKAction *grow = [SKAction scaleTo:1.2 duration:0.1];
        SKAction*shrink = [SKAction scaleTo:0 duration:0.07];
        SKAction *removeNode = [SKAction removeFromParent];
        SKAction *seq = [SKAction sequence:@[grow, shrink, removeNode]];

        [TestObject runAction:seq];
        [self CreateTestObject];

        [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"Sound.aif" waitForCompletion:NO]];

    }
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
for (UITouch *touch in touches) 
    {
    //CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];
    [self selectNodeForTouch:positionInScene];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: It will help if you edit your question and remove the unnecessary code and unnecessary text - like that "you want to learn things" etc. Keep it concise but still understandable.

Comment: when you said "Clicker" I stopped and listened... :)

Comment: http://thelastofus.wikia.com/wiki/The_Infected#Clickers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the max values for your (x,y) coordinates of any object being added to your view.

For example, on an iPhone 5 display in landscape mode and the spawned object being of size width=100, height=100, the max x value should be no more than 518. Width of screen being 568 less half the width of your object (50).

The same logic applies for the y value. The max y value should be 270 given the same object dimensions.

The above assumes that you have not changed your object's anchor point from (0.5,0.5) to another value.

Comment: The answer still applies to any object created in your code. If you spawn new objects you have to range check x and y coordinates. Obviously you are not doing that or you wouldn't have the problem.

Comment: now i write this code:

      int maxX = (283);
      float ranX = (arc4random()%maxX) + 1;
    
      int maxY = (531);
      float ranY = (arc4random()%maxY) + 1;

and i think its work!